# MongoEngine returns empty list

Tags: python, mongodb, mongoengine, flask-mongoengine

I have a database named suvaider. It contains two collection Relation and Reviews. I have filled these two by importing from json files. I have created models for these two collections. But while trying to use these models to get data  with mongoengine it returns empty array.  I'm a beginner I'm using mongodb for the first time with flask. Thanks in advance!!!

```
# This is models.py 
    from flask import url_for
    from suvaiderBackend import db

    class Hotels(db.EmbeddedDocument):
        property_id = db.StringField(max_length=255,required=True)
        name = db.StringField(max_length=255,required=True)

    class Relation(db.Document):
        parent = db.EmbeddedDocumentField('Hotels')
        units = db.ListField(db.EmbeddedDocumentField('Hotels'))

    class Reviews(db.Document):
        property_id = db.StringField(max_length=255,required=True)
        rating = db.IntField(default=0)
        review = db.StringField()
        sentiment = db.StringField(max_length=255)
        review_link = db.StringField()

 #This is __init__.py
        from flask import Flask 
        from flask.ext.mongoengine import MongoEngine
        app = Flask(__name__)
        app.config["MONGODB_SETTINGS"] = {'DB': "suvaider"}
        app.config["SECRET_KEY"] = "Keep3H9Secret"

        db = MongoEngine(app)

        if __name__ == '__main__':
             app.run(debug=true)
```

Answer (score 4):

According to the [documentation](http://docs.mongoengine.org/guide/defining-documents.html#document-collections) Mongoengine by default converts your Document class name to lowercase and use it as a name of the collection. So in your example it looks for collections named: relation and reviews. Since you have existing database with different collections(notice the spelling - first letter uppercase) you should set custom collection name by adding

```
meta = {'collection': 'collectionName'}
```

to your documents.

```
class Relation(db.Document):
    parent = db.EmbeddedDocumentField('Hotels')
    units = db.ListField(db.EmbeddedDocumentField('Hotels'))
    meta = {'collection': 'Relation'}

class Reviews(db.Document):
    property_id = db.StringField(max_length=255,required=True)
    rating = db.IntField(default=0)
    review = db.StringField()
    sentiment = db.StringField(max_length=255)
    review_link = db.StringField()
    meta = {'collection': 'Reviews'}
```

Answer (score -2):

Basically, I found that adding

```
'allow_inheritance': True
```

in your meta forces mongoengine to somehow return empty lists. So getting rid of it helped me.